# Bluetooth paired signal

Tags: atmega, bluetooth

I'm using Atmega8 with HC-05 bluetooth module for communication with android bluetooth.
The connection was success. But i want microcontroller to detect whether the HC-05 is connected with android or not ?? Is it possible? if yes please provide the solution.

Comment: Have the android say "I am here" over bluetooth on connect.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [HC 05 AT-command set](http://robopoly.epfl.ch/files/content/sites/robopoly/files/Tutoriels/bluetooth/hc-05-at_command_set.pdf), you can verify if the module is paired (and the title of your question suggests, that this is what you need).
Please check the AT+STATE? command on page 16:

The command: AT+STATE?
Response: +STATE:[Param] 
where [Param] denotes the state:
"INITIALIZED", "READY", "PAIRABLE", "PAIRED", "INQUIRING", "CONNECTING", "CONNECTED", "DISCONNECTED", "NUKNOW" (unknonwn - isn't it a mistake? shouldn't it be "UNKNOWN"?)

**Update**

In the document [HC Serial Bluetooth Products
User Instructional Manual](http://www.exp-tech.de/service/datasheet/HC-Serial-Bluetooth-Products.pdf), on page 32 you can find the following information (original spelling):

> PIN32 - Output terminal. Before paired, it output low level. Once the pair is finished, it output high level.